# Entity with one 1:1 relation and 1:many - setting up foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this simple model and I'd want to configure relations between them

one Company has one logo

and one Company can have many files

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public File Logo { get; set; }

    public List<File> Attachments { get; set; } = new List<File>();
}

public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }  

    (...)
}

public class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
            .WithOne(x => x.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyId);

        builder
           .HasOne(x => x.Logo)
           .WithOne(x => x.Company)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.); // x. doesnt show me anything about "File" class. It looks like assembly

    }
}
```

But since I probably neeed two `FK`

I changed it into:

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }  

    public Company CompanyOtherProperty { get; set; }
    public int CompanyOtherPropertyId { get; set; }
}
```

but even if I insert FK's name as a string

```
public class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
            .WithOne(x => x.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyId);

        builder
           .HasOne(x => x.Logo)
           .WithOne(x => x.CompanyOtherProperty)
           .HasForeignKey("CompanyOtherPropertyId");
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'You are configuring a relationship between 'Company' and 'File' but have specified a foreign key on 'CompanyOtherPropertyId'. The foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the relationship.'

Answer (score 1):

Given your needs, I would do this using inheritance since Logo and Attachements have common properties but not the same relations

```
public abstract class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .....
}

public class Logo : File
{
    ....
}

public class Attachement : File
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Logo Logo { get; set; }

    public int LogoId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Attachement> Attachements { get; set; } = new List<Attachement>();

}
```

```
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

public DbSet<Attachement> Attachements { get; set; }

public DbSet<Logo> Logos { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<File>().HasDiscriminator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The design you have right now is error prone, I assume one file cannot be both Logo and Attachment which means one of the two Company navigation properties will always be null. You will have to do null checks everywhere in the system

You should have separate models for `File` and `Logo`